# converting arguments to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function and I pass it an object and some arguments. EX:

```
someFunc: function(obj){

     var cra = Array.prototype.call(arguments);
```

so, I call this function passing the following arguments:

```
someFunc({name: 'frank', age: '56', Location: 'New Heaven'}, 'name, 'age');
```

I want to have the new Array created "cra" contain all the arguments except the first argument argument[0] which is an object.

A for loop does not work and I don't want to use loops here. Is there something I am missing?

basically:

```
console.log(cra): 
>>> ['name','age']
```

Comment: You can use shift function to remove the first argument of an Array.

Comment: `cra.shift()` would modify the array to be what you want, `cra.slice(1)` would return what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use

```
function argArray(){
    return Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 1);
}
```

usage:

```
argArray(1,2,3,4); // [2,3,4]
```

This is like doing `[1,2,3,4].splice(1);`, with the added bonus that you are casting `arguments` to an `Array` object.